# CapsLock Escape flip button

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys, capslock, remapping

I'm trying to map capslock to escape,I put those lines in a file `.speedswapper` and then executed `xmodmap .speedswapper`.

```
! Swap caps lock and escape                                                     
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
!keysym Escape = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Escape
add Lock = Caps_Lock
```

All good, except when I switch language using the shortcut 'windows + space'and switch back, it' back to English language, but caps-lock back too!!
I need to map caps-lock to escape for ever, note: `xmodmap .speedswapper` with those lines of code can't be run if the caps-lock already mapped, and thus I can't use `bashrc` file.

Comment: I  wanna make the script executed every time language switched to english... or at least not to switch back when switch language to Arabic, @DavidFoerster

Comment: when I execute that script, caps-lock is mapped to escape, all good, when I switch language to Arabic, and switch back to English, caps-lock is caps-lock, it's not mapped any more..  @DavidFoerster

Comment: let's say you want to map caps-lock to escape, how do you do it ? @DavidFoerster

Comment: the one above in the question, may be it's not called a script, but I put those lines in a file and executed this command : 'xmodmap the_file_path.sh' @DavidFoerster

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the whole thing. Again, could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place and the edit will trigger an election to reopen the question. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Yes sure I will, thanks for your patience... @DavidFoerster

Comment: @DavidFoerster I just updated the question..

Comment: @DavidFoerster I edited the question, don't know if the question is reopened or not !

Comment: Sorry, I don't think what I had in mind would work after all (or I forgot its crucial point).

Comment: @DavidFoerster don't worry it's okay, thanks for your time!